# Describe Function in PySpark 2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I received the following error in my `.describe()` function using PySpark.

It seems every thing is there in the correct path, but it does not work.

Any help is appreciated!

Following the trace:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o31.describe.
>       : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.aggResult$lzycompute$1(StatFunctions.scala:273)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$stat$StatFunctions$$aggResult$1(StatFunctions.scala:273)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$$anonfun$summary$2.apply$mcVI$sp(StatFunctions.scala:286)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.summary(StatFunctions.scala:285)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.summary(Dataset.scala:2473)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.describe(Dataset.scala:2412)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Comment: So you can get the help you need please look at how to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: post code snippet for which you are getting error